# Given a vector, find others vectors which form 90º with the first

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I've got a vector v = (3,-1). The thing is I need to find other vectors so that the angle between them forms 90º. We are talking about R^2.

I have thought about using the following formula:

[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd5pF.png)

However, I don't seem to reach any correct answers with this method, & I don't know if I am approaching this problem the correct way. Any help please?

Comment: The vector $v$ that you have in your question is in $\mathbb{R}^2$ , not $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it. However, I still need to find the vector.

Comment: When two vectors are perpendicular their dot product is zero. You can finish by letting the other vector be {x,y}, computing the dot product and setting that equal to zero. You should get 3x = y, so any {x,y} on that line works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $v = (3, -1) $ and a perpendicular vector $w = (x, y) $, you want

$ v \cdot w = 0 $

which according to the formula that listed, ensures that the angle between $v$ and $w$ is $90^\circ$.

This means that we want

$ v \cdot w = 3 x- y = 0 $

which is the line $ y = 3 x$.  Any point on this line gives a vector $w$ that is perpendicular to $v$.

Comment: So you are saying that, for instance, let's give x the value of 10. That would make y = 30. And so on. If that's what you are saying, my results checker tells me it is wrong, even though I get what you are trying to say.

Comment: @PMathC I don’t know about your “results checker”, but $(10,30)$ is a valid solution.